# Организация GIT для небольшой команды разработчиков.

Tags: git

Доброго дня всем!

В Сети много ссылок на настройку GIT, как локально, так и с онлайн-хранилищами. Но я нигде не нашёл рекомендаций по правильной организации такого хранилища. Итак, имеем небольшую (3-5 человек) команду разработчиков (на C++/Qt). На компьютерах настроена переменная окружения (например, prog_root), внутри которой есть:

1. Папки разработчиков (bill,bob,john), внутри которых каждый разработчик хранит свои программы (папка разработчика является корневой для проектов Qt Creator).
2. Папка include, в которой хранятся заголовочные файлы (и .cpp) для совместно используемых программных модулей. Внутри неё тоже есть папки (common, math, exceptions etc.), в которых хранятся <библиотеки>, относящиеся к соответствующей предметной области.
3. Папка lib, в которую складываются сгенерированные статические библиотеки.
4. Папка build, в которой генерятся исполняемые файлы.
5. Папка doc, в которой хранится документация
6. Прочее.

Каждый разработчик пишет как отдельные программы (обменивающиеся информацией по TCP/IP, через разделяемую память, через перенаправление потоков ввода-вывода или ещё как), так и библиотеки, используемые другими программистами. Исходники библиотек хранятся в include и могут включаться в несколько проектов сразу.

В настоящее время обмен свежими версиями происходит так: выпустив важное изменение и отладив на своей машине, разработчик говорит остальным: "заберите у меня такой-то файл", те забирают и копируют на свои машины. Иногда, когда отладка возможна только на специфических данных или оборудовании, доступных только на объекте, разработчик едет на объект, отлаживается и привозит обратно отлаженную версию, которую раскидывает себе и предлагает забрать другим разработчикам. Синхронизация версий, например, на рабочем компе и на ноутбуке (поработать на дому) осуществляется собственными силами, нецентрализованно. Разработка кросплатформенная, поэтому у некоторых разработчиков есть копии prog_root под Windows, Linux и QNX.

Соответственно, есть желание настроить GIT для того, чтобы свести "размазанную по компьютерам разработчиков" актуальную версию в единое хранилище. Что включать в проект GIT? Если делать по отдельному проекту на программу, библиотеки будут дублироваться, и при переключении на другой проект можно "засосать" устаревшую версию, выложенную при  очередном коммите другим разработчиком. Если по проекту GIT на смысловую единицу, то в одну программу будет входить несколько GIT-проектов. Это правильно? Или надо вообще объединить всё в единой единице GIT?

Если такая тема где-то уже поднималась, буду рад ссылочке. Если нет - рекомендациям по организации хранилища.

Comment: Посмотрите на bitbucket.

Там 5 команда в 5 человек бесплатно может содержать неограниченное кол-во проектов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как обычно делают. На каждый проект делается свой проект. Для библиотек - свой. Потом библиотеки подключаются как [подмодули](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8) к основным проектам. Почему так? Очень часто бывает, что один разработчик пилит библиотеку, а другой использует. И вот разработчик библиотки запилил новый, красивый интерфейс, но сильно не совместимый с старым (это может быть по разному, к примеру, использовалась библиотека не совсем правильно, недокументировано, а в новой версии это прикрыли). Или другой случай, новая библиотека вышла, проекты подтянули для них и через месяц забыли. А потом оказалось, что нужно посмотреть старый-старый код. И что, гадать, какие версии библиотек использовались?

Подмодули позволяют коммитить в основной проект версию вложенных проектов и все будет красиво. Более того, разные разработчики могут использовать разные версии (коммиты) библиотеки. В Вашем случае наверное вначале можно сделать просто один подпроект - библиотека, а потом, по мере надобности разделять.

Теперь дальше. Для удобной работы с кодом, лучше завести github или bitbucket. Последний хорош тем, что позволяет делать приватные репозитории для небольших групп бесплатно. Если код очень сильно секретный и выложить во внешний мир никак нельзя - поставьте себе личный сервер в офис с установленным gitlab. В интернете гуглиться много готовых инструкций, вот к примеру для [ubuntu + gitlab](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-gitlab-as-your-very-own-private-github-clone).

Что хранить в репозиториях. Тут ответ очень прост. Новый разработчик (или старый, который потерял свой комп) должен установить инструменты (компиляторы, ide, git), потом слить репозиторий и начать работать.
Отсюда вывод - в репозитории не нужно хранить всякие `*.o`, `*.bak` или другие бинарники, которые и так можно сгенерировать. Если наличие некоторых бинарников жизненно важно для начала работы и они могут быть скомпилированы - просто добавьте батник/bash файл/perl/python файл который все сам соберет.
Также многие не рекомендуют включать в репозиторий конфиги среды разработки. Они у каждого свои. Но можно добавить "дефолтные" и обновлять их только по общему согласию.

Comment: Спасибо!

Буду гуглить на тему подключения подмодулей. Хочу уточнить слово "проект". Вот у нас система работающая состоит из нескольких программ. Мы делаем систему проектом, а отдельные программы - подмодулями, и библиотеки тоже подмодулями, так?

На тему онлайн-репозитория я уже разбирался, тоже нацелился на bitbucket. Если начальство не решится сырцы в Сети размещать, в качестве локального хранилища достаточно вообще Android-коробочки с Servers Ultimate, там минут за 5 можно всё настроить.

Comment: А как быть в случае "поехал на объект, там всё отладил и откидал исходники обратно"? Копировать сырцы в обход GIT или через него как-то можно сделать?

Comment: гит позволяет локально коммитить (без подключения к серверу). Поэтому, приехал на объект (с ноутом, я так понимаю), сделал ветку (пока локальную), все отладил, можно коммитить много и густо. Приехал в офис - сделал push (теперь все коллеги смогут посмотреть, если хотят). Отладил в офисе, смерджил в мастер/девелом, все пользуются.

Отдельные программы не нужно делать "подмодулями". В одном git проекте может быть несколько "программ", делите по логике. Если есть редактор прошивки и ее заливщик, то наверное их можно вместе разместить.